# Windows Phone 7 Developer

Tags: windows-phone-7

If I plan to deploy my application to my windows phone 7 and i'm a developer, I know that you need to register in the rtdeveloper.windowsphone.com then register your windows live. But the problem is that, whenever i try to finish signing up my information that I am from Singapore but literally from Philippines, it won't load the next page. Do developers for Windows Phone 7 have limitation on which country they could deploy market with?

Comment: I think this is better suited for a Microsoft sites. Have you looked for a FAQ or whatsover?

Comment: That's the official apphub of microsoft site for windows phone 7.

Comment: Have you tried changing your IP address pointing to Singapore?

Comment: what country does your Live ID say you live in? make sure it says Singapore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the FAQ on registration there's no mention of restrictions on Countries. On which page do you have problem ?

Step 1: Choose an account type

Step 2: Enter your personal details

Step 3: Enter your profile information

Step 4: Enter payment information

Step 5: Confirmation page

I think you can access the forum with only a Windows Live ID, there's one specific to registration:
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/88.aspx